# How can I 'fake' stats for generate_series data?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

With 9.1 and earlier, using `generate_series` in the `select` clause does not increase the expected row count (but of course does increase the actual row count), leading to possible poor planning:

```sql
select split_part(version(),' ',2);
/*
 split_part
------------
 9.1.4
*/
explain analyze 
    select foo, generate_series(1,10) 
    from (select 'A' as foo) z
;
/*
                                            QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.014 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
*/
```

note: `(cost=0.00..0.02`***rows=1***`width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.014`***rows=10***`loops=1)`

This is improved in 9.2, giving the standard 1000 estimate:

```sql
select split_part(version(),' ',2);
/*
 split_part
------------
 9.2.1
*/
explain analyze 
    select foo, generate_series(1,10) 
    from (select 'A' as foo) z
;
/*
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.014..0.020 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
*/
```

note: `(cost=0.00..5.02`***rows=1000***`width=32) (actual time=0.014..0.020`***rows=10***`loops=1)`

How can I 'fake' this behaviour in 9.1 and earlier?

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs when using the Set Returning Function in the SELECT target-list, but that way of calling these functions is kludgy in the first place.

See for example [this thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2012-07/msg01101.php) on pg-hackers list on various reasons why experienced PG users tend to avoid it.

On the other hand, when the SRF is called in the FROM list, without the fake cross join, 9.1.6 produces the standard estimate too:

```
 explain analyze 
 select * from (select 'A' as foo) z, generate_series(1,10) b;
```

results in:

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.52 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=0.018..0.041 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series b  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.021 rows=10 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.076 ms
(4 rows)
```

Comment: It might be kludgy but it is sometimes very useful and has been around for a *long* time on pg

Comment: ["Most of the real use-cases for them could be handled in a better-defined, more standard way with LATERAL ... so what we ought to be spending time on is getting LATERAL done"](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2012-07/msg01110.php). Looks like [it might land in 9.3](http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/)

Answer (score 1):

Perform a dummy `cross join` on a single row `generate_series`:

```sql
select split_part(version(),' ',2);
/*
 split_part
------------
 9.1.4
*/
explain analyze 
    select foo, generate_series(1,10) 
    from (select 'A' as foo) z 
    cross join generate_series(1,1)
;
/*
                                                       QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.52 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.022..0.026 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
*/
```

note: `(cost=0.00..22.52`***rows=1000***`width=32) (actual time=0.022..0.026 rows=10 loops=1)`

Comment: Why is this working?

Comment: because it only 'fails' if the `generate_series` is in the select–postgres's weird sort of accidental version of `cross apply`